# Complex list comparisons in python

Tags: python, list, comparison

I want to do a complex list comparison with python. I want to see if `listB` contains all of the items from `listA` and if they are in the same order. But I do not care if `listB` has extra items or interleaved items.

Examples:

```
listA = ['A','B','C','D','E']
listB = [':','A','*','B','C','D','E','`']
```

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` all appear in `listB` and are presented in the same order even though `A` and `B` have an item in between them and items at the start and end of `listB`.

Extra complicated:

```
listA = ['A','B','C','D','E']
listB = ['A','*','C','B','C','D','E']
```

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` all appear in `listB` and are presented in the same order even though `A` and `B` have two items in between them and one of those items happens to be something we are searching for. But since we are looking if `A` -> `B` is sequential and `B` -> `C` is sequential the fact that we also have `C` -> `B` -> `C` shouldn't matter.

So,

```
listA = ['A','B','C','D','E']
listB = [':','A','*','B','C','D','E','`']
```

Would be True

```
listA = ['A','B','C','D','E']
listB = ['A','*','C','B','C','D','E']
```

Would be True

But something like:

```
listA = ['A','B','C','D','E']
listB = ['A','B','C','D','F']
```

or even

```
listB = ['A','B','C','D']
```

Would be False

If it get a False answer, I'd ideally like to be able to point to where the break in sequence happened -- i.e. `E is missing`.

Comment: We don't need so many examples, your description is perfectly clear. What we do need is for you to show some effort in trying to solve it, we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Turn List A into a regular expression with `.*` between each element. Turn List B into a string. Then test if the string matches the regular expression.

Comment: Are the items always unique? How should duplicates be handled?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651891/longest-common-subsequence-in-python

Comment: Created a dedicated iterator for `listB`, then use nested `for` loops to walk through `listA` and `listB` at the same time. (Hint: you'll take *at least* one step on `listB` for each step you take on `listA`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using a nested loop. Walk over listA and search the elements in listB in order. Should you fail at any point -> this is not a substring:

```
def check(listA, listB):
    start = 0
    for a in listA:
        for i in range(start, len(listB)):
            if a == listB[i]:
                start = i+1
                break
        else:  # triggered only if no break
            # print(f'{a} not found after position {start}')
            return False
    return True

check('ABCDE', 'A*CBCDE')
# True

check('ABCDEF', 'A*CBCDE')
# False

check ('', '')
# True

check('ABA', 'ABBA')
# True
```

*NB. Using strings here for clarity, but this works for any iterable.*

To get information on the non-found item, you can uncomment the `print`.

Example:

```
check('ABCA', 'ABBA')

C not found after position 2
# False
```

Comment: Sorry @Dani our edits crossed ;) and thanks

Comment: This is most comprehensively what I was trying to do, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Recursive Solution**

```
def is_contained(a, b):
    # Base case
    if not a or not b:
        return True if not a else False
    
    # if first letters match check remaining, else check b remaining
    return is_contained(a[1:], b[1:]) if a[0] == b[0] else is_contained(a, b[1:])
```

**Test**

```
print(is_contained(['A','B','C','D','E'], ['A','*','C','B','C','D','E']))  # True
print(is_contained(['A','B','C','D','E'], ['A','B','C','D','F']))          # False
```

Answer (score 1):

As always Python comes with batteries included, use [`SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) for a one-line solution:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


def check(lstA, lstB):
    sm = SequenceMatcher(isjunk=lambda x: x not in set(lstA), a=lstA, b=lstB)
    return sum(block.size for block in sm.get_matching_blocks()) == len(lstA) 

print(check(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [':', 'A', '*', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', '`']))
print(check(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', '*', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']))
print(check(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
False
```

Notice that this also works for any sequence, like strings:

```
print(check('ABCDE', 'A*CBCDE'))
print(check('ABCDEF', 'A*CBCDE'))
print(check('', ''))
print(check('ABA', 'ABBA'))
```

**Output** *(for strings)*

```
True
False
True
True
```

`SequenceMatcher` will even give information on how to transform one sequence into the other:

```
listA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
listB = [':', 'A', '*', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', '`']
s = SequenceMatcher(None, listA, listB)
for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
    print('{:7}   a[{}:{}] --> b[{}:{}] {!r:>8} --> {!r}'.format(tag, i1, i2, j1, j2, listA[i1:i2], listB[j1:j2]))
```

**Output**

```
insert    a[0:0] --> b[0:1]       [] --> [':']
equal     a[0:1] --> b[1:2]    ['A'] --> ['A']
insert    a[1:1] --> b[2:3]       [] --> ['*']
equal     a[1:5] --> b[3:7] ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] --> ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
insert    a[5:5] --> b[7:8]       [] --> ['`']
```